# Ramda, test two objects with multiple predicates for props equality

Tags: ramda.js

I have two objects that have the same props. I created few predicates to test them based on business logic:

```
const eqId = eqProps('equipmentId');
const eqQuantity = eqProps('quantity');
const eqColor = eqProps('color');
```

Each predicate accepts (o1, o2) as parameters. I am looking for a nicer way to output single value based on all predicates passing... in other words:

`predicates.every(predicate => predicate(o1, o2) === true)`

but in a more ramda style. `allPass` almost works but it accepts only a single object.
I know I can do this with `every` but this question is to help me learn more how to compose functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] allPass almost works but it accepts only a single object

Perhaps I'm not understanding 100% but I don't think that is true. The documentation says:

> The function returned is a curried function whose arity matches that of the highest-arity predicate.

So given `eqProps('foo')` returns a binary function then the function returned by `allPass` will also be a binary function:

```js
const check = allPass([eqProps('lunch'), eqProps('at')]);

check({lunch: '', at: '1pm'}, {lunch: '', at: '2pm'});
//=> false

check({lunch: '', at: '1pm'}, {lunch: '', at: '1pm'});
//=> true
```

If you have a "blueprint" for what your objects should look like, then I find `eqBy(whereEq)` easier to the eyes.

`eqBy` is better illustrated with an example. Hopefully this needs no further explanation:

```js
const streqi = eqBy(toLower); // case insensitive equality

streqi("Foo", "fOO");
//=> true
```

So going back to `eqBy(whereEq)`:

```js
const check = eqBy(whereEq({lunch: '', at: '1pm'}))

check({lunch: '', at: '1pm', name: 'john'}, {lunch: '', at: '1pm', name: 'tom'});
//=> true

check({lunch: '', at: '1pm', name: 'john'}, {lunch: '', at: '2pm', name: 'tom'});
//                      ^                                       ^
//=> false
```

Comment: Ah! You're right. I missed that part about arity and tried to `allPass([q,t], a, b)` which didn't work. My bad and the solution was just before my eyes.

Comment: @Mike: Ramda has a few function like this that take an array and return a function that somehow combines those functions.  `pipe`, and `compose` are similar and will hopefully one day become like them. `allPass` is among them.  They are oddities in Ramda in that there's no fully applied version.  I'm don't think there's a great reason that the fully applied function isn't available (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author), but we've never done it that way for these sorts of functions.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thx for explanation. Once I got to know this I start to notice those fine details. And a little extra example in the docs wouldn't hurt :)

Comment: @Mike: That would be great.  Feel free to open a [Pull Request](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/compare) or add an [Issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

We need to nest `R.allPass` and `R.all` since it is a matrix-like problem

```js
const a = { suit: '♠︎', rank: '4' };
const b = { suit: '♠︎', rank: '9' };


const isSpade = R.propEq('suit', '♠︎');
const isCard = R.has('suit');

const compareWith = R.pipe(
  R.allPass,
  R.all,
  R.unapply,
);

const isASpadeCard = compareWith([isSpade, isCard])

console.log(
  isASpadeCard(a, b),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This will test array of objects while I want to compare two objects to each other.